# can you call a function within the callong of a function in c

Tags: c

Lets say I have 2 functions `func1()` and `func2(s)` (just names for easy refrence)

to use `func1()` i need to run `func2(s)` which is a void with a pointer to characters in it's decleration: `func2(char *string_one){};`

can I do this: `func1(firststring,func2(s));` in which i add firststring to the result of `func2()` using 2 pointers just like in `func2()`?

`func1()` decleration: `func1(char *string_one, char *string_two){};`

Comment: `func2` should return a `char*`.

Comment: [Function Pointer will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `void` as return type of `func2` doesn't allow to use it as a `char *` parameter of `func1`. You have to return `char *` from `func2`: `char* func2(char* string_one) { }`.

Comment: I changed it to `char*` bu i get an warning: `implicit declaration of function ‘func1’ ` and an error `invalid use of void expression`

Comment: 1) Then declare `func1` before the first usage 2) I don't understand, provide more detail

Comment: I got it' i diden't change the `void` to `char*` in the header file